# I can't acces tomcat manager from my distant server using ssh

Tags: tomcat

I work on Debien 8 distant server using ssh.
I have installed tomcat7 and tomcat7-admin using

```
apt-get install
```

I have configuring tomcat-users.xml by adding a new user with manager-gui and admin-gui roles

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="user" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

But when I go to tomcat manager on server_ip:8080/manager/html, authentication fails.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: How is ssh involved here? You seem to be trying to access the server by its IP address through an HTTP interface.

Comment: I am on windows and using putty to configure my distant server, so I can see tomcat index 'it works !' but I cannot log in on tomcat manager to deploy my war application